# Coldfusion: Odd Behavior with Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, object, loops, coldfusion

So, I'm experiencing a very frustrating problem. I am making an AJAX call (via jquery.post()) that sends criteria that are used to filter Coldfusion objects.

The processing is pretty straightforward. First, a check is performed to see if certain filters have been passed in. If a filter exists, then the objects in the session scope are looped through and, if the value of one of the object elements matches any items in the list of filter values, that object is added to an array. Once this process completes for all defined filter types, the arrays of matching objects are stored in a results object (obj.results), passed to the serializeJSON function, and then ultimately returned to the client.

Unfortunately, if there's more than one filter in play, it appears as though the loops are exited prematurely, resulting in the return fewer results than there are matches. If I only deal with one of the two filters included below, I get the full expected results. Likewise, if in each of the arrayappend() calls below I change s[i] to s[i].name (so, appending a string instead of an object), the expected number of results is returned for each filter.

Here's the code using s[i]:

```
<cffunction name="filterObj" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="filterParams" type="struct" required="yes">
    <cfset var s = session.a> <!--- session.a IS AN ARRAY OF CF OBJECTS --->
    <cfset filteredResults = {}>
    <cfset filteredResults.eligibilities = []>
    <cfset filteredResults.agencies = []>
    <cfif isdefined("arguments.filterParams.agency")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s)#" index="i">
            <cfif structkeyexists(s[i],"agency") and
                listfindnocase(arguments.filterParams["agency"],s[i].agency["name"])>
                    <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.agencies, s[i])>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("arguments.filterParams.eligibility")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s)#" index="i">
            <cfif structkeyexists(s[i],"el")>
                <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s[i].eligibility)#" index="e">
                    <cfif listfindnocase(arguments.filterParams["eligibility"],s[i].eligibility[e].type)>
                        <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.eligibilities, s[i])>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfset obj.results = filteredResults>
    <cfset obj = serializeJSON(obj)>
    <cfreturn obj>
</cffunction>
```

Here are the unexpanded console.logged results using s[i]

```
RESULTS: Object
  AGENCIES: Array[5]
  ELIGIBILITIES: Array[5]
```

Here's the code again using s[i].name

```
<cffunction name="filterObj" access="public" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="filterParams" type="struct" required="yes">
    <cfset var s = session.a> <!--- session.a IS AN ARRAY OF CF OBJECTS --->
    <cfset filteredResults = {}>
    <cfset filteredResults.eligibilities = []>
    <cfset filteredResults.agencies = []>
    <cfif isdefined("arguments.filterParams.agency")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s)#" index="i">
            <cfif structkeyexists(s[i],"agency") and
                listfindnocase(arguments.filterParams["agency"],s[i].agency["name"])>
                    <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.agencies, s[i].name)>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("arguments.filterParams.eligibility")>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s)#" index="i">
            <cfif structkeyexists(s[i],"el")>
                <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(s[i].eligibility)#" index="e">
                    <cfif listfindnocase(arguments.filterParams["eligibility"],s[i].eligibility[e].type)>
                        <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.eligibilities, s[i].name)>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfset obj.results = filteredResults>
    <cfset obj = serializeJSON(obj)>
    <cfreturn obj>
</cffunction>
```

Here are the unexpanded console.logged results using s[i].name

```
RESULTS: Object
  AGENCIES: Array[10]
  ELIGIBILITIES: Array[6]
```

I feel like there must be some kind of asynchronous processing of the two loops happening on the server, or that something's timing out before a loop can finish.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Does this function reside in a CFC? 2) How do you invoke the method? (CFINVOKE or via CreateObject, calling the method later), and 3) Do you store this CFC in a shared scope (ie. APPLICATION)?

Comment: First thing I would try is to make sure you are using VAR scope for all loop indexes and temporary variables.

Comment: Hi Shawn,
1) The function does reside in a CFC.
2) It is called via <cfset var jsonObject = createObject("component","#application.componentpath#Component").filterMethod(arguments.filterParams)>
3) CFC is not stored in a shared scope

Comment: I still need to know #2 and #3 to answer definitively.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I hit enter too early.

Comment: What and when do you read and write to SESSION.a?

Comment: session.a is populated with objects the first time a user accesses the site.

Comment: Oh, and the reason I write it to a local var in the function is because I'd like to retain all objects in the session scope, but delete them from the function scope as they are added to the results array (so I can avoid duplicate entries in the results, e.g., when one object matches two filter values).

Also, I did use var to scope temporary variables, but I'm not sure how to do that for loop indexes. Can I just do index="var i"?

Comment: If the CFC isn't stored in a shared scope, variable clash isn't an issue (but you should still follow @Sergii's recommendation). Your question and console log results are misleading: You state if 1 filter or the other is used, results are correct, but together, are incorrect. However, in showing us your debug differences, you refer to a key in the object array (s[i].name) vs. the actual object array (s[i]). This is confusing, as it doesn't describe to us why that would matter / change when single vs. multiple parameters are passed.

Comment: Yes, just var i = 0 is enough to locally declare it and keep it out of the CFC's VARIABLES scope. Alternately, in CF9 and up, you may use the LOCAL scope without having to VAR it (ie. local.i)

Comment: Programmatically, the difference between s[i] and s[i].name is that s[i] returns an object, whereas s[i].name returns a string. Returning a string leads to the correct number of results (10 agencies and 6 eligibilities), whereas returning the full object returns a truncated set (5 agencies and 5 eligibilities). As far as I can tell, the program logic should cause s[i] and s[i].name to return arrays of the same length. Hopefully it's due to some technical aspect of ColdFusion I'm unaware of, or, less likely, some ColdFusion bug.

Apologies for not being more clear on that.

Comment: Here comes the missing link: Returning a string **WHERE**...in your ListFindNoCase() function?

Comment: Ah. My apologies again. I didn't include the modified code that returns the string. If within each outermost conditional you change <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.agencies, s[i])> to <cfset arrayappend(filteredResults.agencies, s[i].name)>, the array will be populated with strings instead of objects. Is it worth editing the original post to clarify that more?

Comment: Yes, that will provide additional clarity.

Comment: Done...thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue in some versions of CF9, as well as CF10, regarding the serialization of an array of objects; you've stumbled across this bug by appending the objects themselves to the return var, as opposed to the string-based keys of said objects.

The bug is reproducible via this simple script:

```
<cfset obj = ArrayNew(1) />

<cfset obj[1] = StructNew() />
<cfset obj[1].name = "Kate" />
<cfset obj[2] = StructNew() />
<cfset obj[2].name = "Ted" />
<cfset obj[3] = StructNew() />
<cfset obj[3].name = "Phil" />

<cfset data = ArrayNew(1) />

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(obj)#" index="i">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(data, obj[i]) />
</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#data#>

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(obj)#" index="i">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(data, obj[i]) />
</cfloop>

<cfdump var=#data#>

<cfoutput>#ArrayLen(data)#</cfoutput>
<cfset json = SerializeJSON(data) />

<cfdump var=#json#>

<cfset converted = DeserializeJSON(json) />
<cfoutput>#ArrayLen(converted)#</cfoutput>
```

The expected result is that the final deserialized array is 6 elements in length, as it was pre-serialization. However, the actual result is 3.

Stick with appending strings, rather than entire objects, to the array var you're returning, if you absolutely must serialize it before returning it from the function, and refactor outlying code that calls this function.

SOURCE: [Problem with serializeJSON -- truncates embedded objects](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4362247)

Comment: Thanks so much. I feel sane again! I have contacted IT to see if they'll install the hotfix. Dealing with it as a JSON string would be doable, but would be a fairly large undertaking (lots of nested information to loop through).

Comment: Nevermind re: the hotfix. I just had a chance to read the user comments on the Adobe forum post that @Shawn posted, and it appears it persists with hotfix 2. So, I went over to the Adobe BugBase and voted this bug up: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3042650

Comment: FYI - the bug discussed in this thread has apparently been fixed in CF10. See here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3175667

We're still running 9 at work so I can't confirm directly...